# Change the text color of an unidentified radio button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

I have a radio group with 4 radio buttons. I use this code :

```
int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);
```

To retrieve the index of the checked radio button.

The problem is that i want to change the text color of the checked radio button, while i dont know the specific radio button each time. so: `checkedRadioButton.setTextColor(color);` 
shows me an error that i need to 'Add a qualifier', which basicaly is showing me that i should use a specific radio button to call that method, like:

`radioButtonAns1.setTextColor(color);`

I would like if someone would also explain why i have that error and if there is a solution on that. The only method i can call is `.setBackgroundColor()` which looks ugly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTextColor` method if you cast the `View` that you found to `RadioButton`:

```
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
checkedRadioButton.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is kinda of straight forward, the error is basically saying hey you trying to change the color of the group containing the groups of radio button.Please choose which one you want first then change the it. To remedy this declare a Boolean array,then set a on click listener to detect the position of the clicked radio button then set then set Boolean value to true in the array.

Comment: The thing is that i try to access the radio button and not the radio group. I just had to specify that i want returned a RadioButton and not a View. Casting it made the trick

Answer (score 0):

An XML alternative would be:

set the `TextColor` as a `@Color` selector.

```
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/radio_1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Radio 1"
   android:textColor="@color/radiobuttonstate"/>
```

The color selector would be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <item android:color="#00f"/>
</selector>
```